# How to print my app's private log by installing a configuration file

Tags: ios, swift

I use the unified logging system to print logs. I know that I can override the behavior of different levels of messages through configuration files, but I don't know how to customize the behavior of subsystems in my app by writing configuration files. My goal is to let the log display private information without using Xcode's debugger mode. I read the configuration files written by Apple, the PayloadType write: 
PayloadType
com.apple.system.logging
But if I write this, I can't install it on my phone.
This is my .mobileconfig file's content:

```
<key>PayloadContent</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>collect log</string>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>live assistant logging</string>
        <key>PayloadEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.system.logging.F3AABD4E-58A7-42C0-971E-B861AFB61937</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>com.apple.system.logging</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>F3AABD4E-58A7-42C0-971E-B861AFB61937</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Subsystems</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.live.assistant</key>
            <dict>
                <key>DEFAULT-OPTIONS</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Enable-Oversize-Messages</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>Enable-Private-Data</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>Level</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Enable</key>
                        <string>Debug</string>
                        <key>Persist</key>
                        <string>Debug</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>Default-Privacy-Setting</key>
                    <string>Public</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```